# Amazon says my SRP_A generation is likely incorrect for Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Can anyone tell what I might be doing wrong as far as generating a SRP_A value (most likely it is at fault anyway) when trying to log someone in is concerned?

For some context, I have been tasked to build a web app using S3 as a front end and AWS Lambda as a backend and in the backend I'm trying to implement logging in a user using 'USER_SRP_AUTH'.  An authentication method I'm fairly un knowledgeable about and it seams like Amazons documentation for their flavor of it, is severely lacking. I assume because they don't expect people to go the route I have to. Lastly I have had to struggle to develop my own API and login page, because of decisions out of my control I can not use Amazons built in log in page.

So far I can send a call to InitiateAuth, but when I attempt to create the challenge response, I get back a "Invalid Username or Password". Both of which I have verified are correct.

I reached out to Amazon and they said it is likely my SRP generation used for the initialize step.

Is Amazon right?  I have tried multiple SRP generation methods, from ones listed in answers here, to ones provided by ChatGPT, but none seam to be correct.

First here is the actual algorithms I have come up with for generating the various values that AWS says are needed.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import {SRPClient } from 'amazon-user-pool-srp-client';
// Mainly helper methods and functions to be used in the auth API
export default class Auth {
    static createSecretHash(username, clientId) {        
        const HMAC = crypto.createHmac("sha256", process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET);                                        
        HMAC.update(username + clientId);
        return HMAC.digest("base64");
    };

    static generatePasswordSecretBlock(password, salt, srpB) {
        const passwordHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(salt + password).digest('hex');
        return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(srpB + passwordHash).digest('hex');        
    }

    static generatePasswordClaimSignature(username, passwordClaimSecretBlock, userIDForSRP) {   
        const HMAC = crypto.createHmac("sha256", process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET);                     
        const message = username + passwordClaimSecretBlock + userIDForSRP;
        return HMAC.update(message).digest('hex');
    }

    static generateSRP(userPoolId) {
        // Generate SRP_A
        const srpClient = new SRPClient(userPoolId);

        // Convert SRP_A to hexadecimal string
        return srpClient.calculateA().toString();
    };   

    // old version - some sources say this doesn't work because the SRP for Amazon is a calculated value.
    // static generateSRP() {
    //     // Generate SRP_A
    //     const srpASizeBits = 256; // Size of SRP_A in bits
    //     const srpA = crypto.randomBytes(srpASizeBits / 8);

    //     // Convert SRP_A to hexadecimal string
    //     return srpA.toString('hex');
    // };    

}
```

And here is how I have implemented the API that uses them.

```
import API from "./api.mjs";
import APIError from "./apiError.mjs";
import Auth from "../auth.mjs";
import _  from "lodash";
import { DateTime} from "luxon";
import {CognitoIdentityProviderClient, InitiateAuthCommand, } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import crypto from 'crypto';

export default class AuthAPI extends API {
    static async get(params, res) {
        res["body"] = "Test"; 
    }

    static postRequiredParams = ['type', 'userName'];
    static async post(params, res) {
        try {           
            if (this.HandleMissingPrimaryParams("post", params, res)) return;
            let requestData = {
                "headers": {
                    "X-Amz-Target": 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.', //Append service type. Ex: InitiateAuth
                    "Content-Type": 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
                },
                "body": "",
                "method": "post"
            };
            let response = {};
            let jsonResponse = {};
        

            const SECRET_HASH = Auth.createSecretHash(params['userName'], process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID);
            
            switch (params['type'].toLowerCase()) {
                case "verify":
                    if (this.HandleMissingParams(params, ['challengeName'], res)) return;
                   
                    let challengeResponseData = {
                        ChallengeName: params['challengeName'],
                        ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
                    };
                    switch (params["challengeName"]) {
                        case "PASSWORD_VERIFIER":
                            if (this.HandleMissingParams(params, ['password', 'salt', 'srpB', 'userIDForSRP'], res)) return;
                            const PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK = Auth.generatePasswordSecretBlock(params['password'], params['salt'], params['srpB']);
                            // Currently unsure when userName and userIDForSRP would be different, but keeping them seperate if they ever differ.
                            const PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE = Auth.generatePasswordClaimSignature(params['userName'], PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK, params['userIDForSRP']);
                            const TIME_STAMP = DateTime.now().toFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").toString();  
                            challengeResponseData['ChallengeResponses'] = {
                                USERNAME: params['userName'],
                                PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK: PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK,
                                PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE: PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE,
                                TIMESTAMP: TIME_STAMP,        
                                SECRET_HASH: SECRET_HASH,                    
                            };                                                
                                
                            break;

                        case "SMS_MFA":
                        case "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE":
                        case "DEVICE_SRP_AUTH":
                        case "DEVICE_PASSWORD_VERIFIER":
                        case "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED":
                        default:
                            throw new APIError(`ChallengeName ${params["challengeName"]}, is not implemented `, 500);
                    }

                    requestData["headers"]["X-Amz-Target"] += "RespondToAuthChallenge";
                    requestData["body"] = JSON.stringify(challengeResponseData);
                              
                    break;

                case "initiate":
                    // First make a login request using SRP Auth.  NOTE: We are making requests with fetch instead of the 
                    // AWS Cognito SDK because it does not accept (for some reason) a SECRET_HASH, which is required for 
                    // our setup.
                    
                    const SRP_A = Auth.generateSRP(process.env.AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID);

                    requestData["headers"]["X-Amz-Target"] += 'InitiateAuth';
                    requestData["body"] = JSON.stringify({
                        ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
                        AuthFlow: "USER_SRP_AUTH",                        
                        AuthParameters: {
                            USERNAME: params['userName'],
                            SRP_A: SRP_A,
                            SECRET_HASH: SECRET_HASH,                            
                        }
                    });                 
                break;

                default:
                    //Invalid option
                    throw new APIError("Invalid auth type", 500);

                break;
            }
            console.log("requestData:", requestData)     
            response = await fetch(process.env.AWS_COGNITO_URL, requestData);
            jsonResponse = await response.json();    
            console.log("response:", response);
            console.log("jsonResponse:", jsonResponse);
            if (response['status'] !== 200 || jsonResponse['error'] !== undefined || jsonResponse['errorMessage'] !== undefined) 
                throw new APIError("Error with auth", response['status'], jsonResponse);
            

            res["body"] = jsonResponse;

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err:', err);
            if (err instanceof APIError) {
                res["statusCode"] = err["status"];
                res["body"] = err["body"];
                res["body"]["error"] = err['message'];
                return;
            }            
            res["statusCode"] = 500;
            res["body"] = err;
            res["body"]["error"] = err['message'];
        };
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.